# Execute single command in shell script without sudo

Tags: bash, homebrew, sudo

I have a simple shell script that is run with sudo as most of the script requires it, yet one of the commands in the script is a Homebrew install, which cannot be executed with sudo..

So, my question is when executing a shell script with sudo how do I execute sub commands as the current user and then continue the remainder of the script with sudo.

Prompting the user to enter his password again is not really practical as the script takes really long to execute and would require waiting 5-10 min for the prompt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is to run the subcommand via `sudo` from within the script. The user id to run with can be obtained by $SUDO_USER (look at the output of `sudo env`):

```
sudo -u $SUDO_USER ./exec_as_normal_user.sh
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the need for another bash script file? AWS allows for only one file as attachement when launching a server

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the shell using

`sudo -u $USER_NAME bash`

and execute the shell script by calling,

./program.sh