# How to execute code as other user within script?

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, su

I'm writing a script which automates the install of a mailserver, however some of my code has to be compiled from source because it is not in repositories. I have no problem with this, however, I have no idea what the best and most safe way is from a script that is being run as root. I know I have to make a non-privileged user for building, but which on of the following is the recommended way to do it?

1

```
su -c "command" - builduser
su -c "othercommand" - builduser
```

2

```
sudo -u builduser command
sudo -u builduser othercommand
```

3

```
su -c "externalscriptwithcommands.sh" - builduser
```

Ideally, I would like to continue my script as root after this has executed; I feel like option 3 is probably the most ideal, but I would like your input on this.

Comment: Look at the answer on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335825/execute-single-command-in-shell-script-without-sudo). As you want to continue as superuser, method 2 should be the best way.

Comment: Also, one option I did not consider is building SRPM-packages which can be installed as usual in the script. Thanks for your input :)